# How TCP works from the client point of view

Tags: networking, tcp, protocols

I know how TCP protocols work from the server point of view. NAT is used to know on which local machine is the port number xx reserved.

When I establish a connection with a server, it opens a non-reserved port. How does my livebox, for example, knows I reserved my port and not an other computer ?

Additional questions:
- For the Client/Server, is there one port per socket ? One per processus ? One per Thread ? 
- On a server, there is a socket listening on a port, once it accepts a connection, does it open a new port ?

Comment: I think you misunderstand TCP. In TCP, there is _no_ concept of client/server. TCP is a peer connection. The client/server concept is an application-layer concept.

Answer (score 0):

> How does my livebox, for example, knows I reserved my port and not an
>   other computer ?

I assume you are talking if the client is behind a NAT.

Is ever the client to contact the server. So when the client send the first packet to the server through your router(that provide for you NATting). The router save into is NAT table the address and the port of the client, so when i get the answer he know who is the client.

[image]

> Additional questions: - For the Client/Server, is there one port per
>   socket ? One per processus ? One per Thread ? - On a server, there is
>   a socket listening on a port, once it accepts a connection, does it
>   open a new port ?

I think you are confusing some concepts.

Into the OSI protocol and into TCP/IP protocol there are differents kind of layers.

[image]

As you can see TCP (Transmission Control Protocol) is under the Application Layer.

When you are talking of *socket* you are into the application layer. So all decisions: 
"Use same port, bind new port for every incoming request" are made by specific application.

> A network socket is an endpoint of a connection across a computer
>   network. Today, most communication between computers is based on the
>   Internet Protocol; therefore most network sockets are Internet
>   sockets. More precisely, a socket is a handle (abstract reference)
>   that a local program can pass to the networking application
>   programming interface (API) to use the connection, for example "send
>   this data on this socket". Sockets are internally often simply
>   integers, which identify which connection to use.

For more about NAT read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation).
For more about Port Forwarding read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding).

Comment: So for example, if I want to connect to a ssh server which is on a server we can not configure, he can send a packet from a port xxx then activate his ssh server and NAT will be enabled for this port ?

Comment: I don't get the correlation between NAT and SSH protocols

Comment: If I have a ssh server but donr configure NAT, nobody outside the network can connect to it. I am proposing a solution to make it possible without having to configure NAT

Comment: "If I have a ssh server but donr configure NAT, nobody outside the network can connect to it" this is not correct. If you have a server, it can be visible if it have a public and unique ip. Otherwise if that server is into a private network it can't be accessible by outside (Also there is a NATting service set on it). 
But this doesn't mean you can't access to a service of your server (for ex. ssh) by a port forwarding set on your router.

Comment: I want to access a ssh server for instance without configuring anything on the router of the server. Typically it is a the connzction of a school

Comment: If your server is into a private network. And it is connected to internet.. The router must have a NAT activated. If you from your home can go on a web site or you can you use a service of that server(as SSH). The router must have set a port forwarding. It's impossible none of these is set.. And you can access to a service or that the server can go through internet.

Comment: @x4rkz for more about the differences between NAT and port-forwarding read here: http://superuser.com/questions/430692/nat-vs-port-forwarding
Moreover as you can imangine usually they are used in combination.